# firewall log entries

Tags: pfsense

I have been having issues with dropped traffic.  I am running pfsense firewall.  I have found the following log entries in the firewall.  These entries suggest to me that the connection to our ISP is shaky at these times.  The times in the logs correlate at least roughly to times when our data (video) stream is disrupted.  Am I on the right track here, or do these entries mean something else?

```
Apr 26 17:10:38     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Alarm latency 6734us stddev 125us loss 21%
Apr 26 17:15:02     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Clear latency 6752us stddev 125us loss 19%
Apr 26 17:15:12     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Alarm latency 6758us stddev 84us loss 21%
Apr 26 17:26:10     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Clear latency 6723us stddev 142us loss 18%
Apr 26 17:26:30     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Alarm latency 6724us stddev 124us loss 21%
Apr 26 17:29:35     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Clear latency 6735us stddev 114us loss 19%
Apr 26 17:29:37     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Alarm latency 6757us stddev 225us loss 21%
Apr 26 17:30:21     dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Clear latency 6720us stddev 233us loss 17% 



May 3 16:10:05  dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Alarm latency 6716us stddev 157us loss 22%
May 3 16:11:19  dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Clear latency 6692us stddev 109us loss 14%
May 3 17:21:39  dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Alarm latency 6722us stddev 116us loss 21%
May 3 17:23:35  dpinger         GW_WAN 24.225.24.1: Clear latency 6705us stddev 122us loss 10%
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Thank you @Ricardo.
I also have logs from my rtmp server showing stream dropped/network unreachable that coincide to the minute with the entries on May 3.  The question is whether this is enough for me to take to my ISP and hound them, or might the issue with these drops be internal somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that the logs are an indication that you might be having a network issue. If you are using dpinger with a resolution of less than 5 minutes, then it looks like you have some sustained performance degradation events, one of them of more than 10 minutes.

I would look for more conclusive information, for example, saturation on the network at that time, lost packets in the stream , and stats from the video players, if available.